# Kubernetes RBAC default user

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, docker-for-mac

I'm reading myself currently into RBAC and am using Docker For Desktop with a local Kubernetes cluster enabled.

If I run `kubectl auth can-i get pods` which user or group or serviceaccount is used by default?

Is it the same call like:

`kubectl auth can-i get pods --as docker-for-desktop --as-group system:serviceaccounts` ?

`kubectl config view` shows:

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-for-desktop-cluster
    namespace: default
    user: docker-for-desktop
  name: docker-for-desktop
...
users:
- name: docker-for-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

But simply calling `kubectl auth can-i get pods --as docker-for-desktop` returns NO.

Thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

> If I run `kubectl auth can-i get pods` which user or group or serviceaccount is used by default?

As you can read on [Configure Service Accounts for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/):

> When you (a human) access the cluster (for example, using `kubectl`), you are authenticated by the apiserver as a particular User Account (currently this is usually `admin`, unless your cluster administrator has customized your cluster). Processes in containers inside pods can also contact the apiserver. When they do, they are authenticated as a particular Service Account (for example, `default`).

You can use `kubectl get serviceaccount` to see what `serviceaccounts` are setup in the cluster.
Try checking which contexts you have available and switching into a which ever you need:

`kubectl config get-contexts`

`kubectl config use-context docker-for-desktop`

If you are experiencing an issue with missing `Role` please check [Referring to Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources) to set  they correctly for `docker-for-desktop`